# std::back_inserter needs const_reference on older GCC. Why?

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I am currently looking at some code that can be compiled on newer versions of GCC but not on older ones. In my case I am using a `std::back_inserter` to `std::copy` some data from one data structure to a custom data structure. If I forget the `typedef value_type & const_reference` typedef in this custom data structure however, this will not compile on GCC 4.4. The same code compiles and runs just fine on GCC 4.5.

What is the difference in between these two compiler versions, that makes the code compile on one version but not on the other. I would guess it has something to do with the implementation of C++11 which was much less complete in GCC 4.4. Probably something with `decltype` or another new C++11 keyword, I would guess.

Also is this code correct, if I use the `std::back_inserter` without defining the `const_reference` type? I usually thought that one has to implement the full set of typedefs (`value_type`, `reference`, `const_reference` etc) in order to be compatible with the STL-algorithms library? Or can I safely assume that if my code compiles in this case I am not invoking anything dangerous (e.g. move semantics, which would destroy my other datastructure).

Comment: For the record (to help beginners like myself save time): After I added   
    `typedef  T& reference;  
    typedef const T& const_reference;`  
to my data structure, the error c2039 for back_inserter is gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard (1998) says that `std::back_insert_iterator` needs `Container::const_reference`. In "24.4.2.1 Template class back_insert_iterator", [lib.back.insert.iterator], it says:

```
back_insert_iterator<Container>&
operator=(typename Container::const_reference value);
```

The 2011 standard only wants `Container::value_type`,

```
back_insert_iterator<Container>&
operator=(const typename Container::value_type& value);
back_insert_iterator<Container>&
operator=(typename Container::value_type&& value);
```

So, to be compatible with both versions of the C++ standard, define both `value_type` and `const_reference_type`.

In both GCC 4.4.6 and 4.5.1, the definition of `operator=` is identical (`libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator.h`):

```
  back_insert_iterator&
  operator=(typename _Container::const_reference __value)
  {
    container->push_back(__value);
    return *this;
  }
```

and I get the same error with both compilers, perhaps you'll need to double check if you're using the correct compiler versions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. On 4.5.2 it works without the const_reference type, as I just verified. 4.4.4 still needs it.

Comment: @LiKao, in recent GCCs, the C++0x library compatibility is enabled by default. GCC4.5.2 is slightly *more* compatible :) than GCC 4.4 in that it uses `const_reference` only when the compatibility is disabled, whereas 4.4 uses it unconditionally.

Comment: @chill: Quoting [the documentation of the current gcc version](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Standards.html#Standards): `The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu++98.`. So, are you sure about what you say?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you need `const_reference` defined for your data-structure is because the assignment operator in GCC 4.4 for an lvalue argument type in the `std::back_insert_iterator` class is defined as:

```
template<class Container>
back_insert_iterator<Container>& 
back_insert_iterator<Container>::operator= 
                  (typename Container::const_reference value);
```

Thus `const_reference` needs to be a resolvable identifier in your class-type in to properly instantiate the assignment operator in the `std::back_insert_iterator` class template.

In GCC 4.5, this definition of the assignment operator for lvalue arguments has been changed to

```
template<class Container>
back_insert_iterator<Container>&
back_insert_iterator<Container>::operator=
                 (const typename Container::value_type& value);
```

in order to support the new C++11 specification.  Since your code compiles correctly with GCC 4.5, I'm assuming you must have `value_type` properly defined for your data-structure.